# Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\ORMException: "Unknown Entity namespace alias 'AppBundle'."

Tags: php, entity-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I just started my first project with composer and wanted to set up the database and the classes for it. However I'm stuck. I'm getting the above error in the prod.log

I followed this tutorial here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

I created the database

`php bin/console doctrine:database:create`

then wanted to create an entity

`php bin/console doctrine:generate:entity`

When asked for the `The Entity shortcut name` I entered `AppBundle:Product`

and then created the database fields etc.

And I'm getting this message

> Entity generation
>
> Generating entity class src/AppBundle/Entity/Product.php: OK!
>   Generating repository class src/AppBundle/Repository/ProductRepository.php: OK!
>
> Everything is OK! Now get to work :).

So this sounds like everything worked, right?

Now in my `ProductController` I used this

```
$products = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')
    ->findAll();
```

and I'm getting the error

```
[2016-02-15 18:56:14] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\ORMException: "Unknown Entity namespace alias 'AppBundle'." at /home/vagrant/work/homestead/test/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/ORMException.php line 271 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\ORM\\ORMException(code: 0): Unknown Entity namespace alias 'AppBundle'. at /home/vagrant/work/homestead/test/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/ORMException.php:271)"} []
```

I also tried

```
->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Product')
```

but here I'm getting the message

```
[2016-02-15 19:01:39] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: "The class 'AppBundle\Entity\Product' was not found in the chain configured namespaces " at /home/vagrant/work/homestead/test/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php line 37 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\Common\\Persistence\\Mapping\\MappingException(code: 0): The class 'AppBundle\\Entity\\Product' was not found in the chain configured namespaces  at /home/vagrant/work/homestead/test/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php:37)"} []
```

How do I actually get this to work/ I just started with the project. Doctrine created the classes though. I have it like this

```
/src
/src/AppBundle/
/src/AppBundle/Entity
    Product.php
/src/AppBundle/Repository
    ProductRepository.php
```

Also, in the Product.php this is in the comments of the annotations (if it helps)

```
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
```

Also, when trying this command `php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle` to recreate the entities I'm getting no error message.

I'm getting

```
Generating entities for bundle "AppBundle"
 > backing up Product.php to Product.php~
 > generating AppBundle\Entity\Product
```

Comment: I'm guessing you may have files under AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine? If so then they are interfering with your annotations.  And did you make any changes to the doctrine section in app/config/config.yml?

Comment: I don't have a folder `AppBundle/Resources`. I always selected `annotations` when creating the entities, so there shouldn't be any configs, right? No, I made no changes in the `app/config/config.yml`

Comment: After generating you need to `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`.
Than check your `namespace` in `Controller` must be `AppBundle\Entity\Product`.

Comment: I created the tables. Sorry if I didn't mention it. I can connect on it and see the new tables. I also used the command you told. The Doctrine docs also state that you can use either `AppBundle:Product` or `AppBundle\Entity\Product` and I already tried that too

Comment: Check your doctrine/orm/auto_mapping set in true in config.yml

Comment: Yes, it is set tot rue

Comment: And cache manually delete I presume?

Comment: How would I do that? Simply delete all contents of /var/cache/prod?

Comment: yes, and then try again, also delete the dev folder if exist.

Comment: Can't believe it. That fixed it. Shouldn't that be somehow done automatically?

Comment: Only if you have been working in debug mode, in production you need to do manually. Also the most secure way is by hand :-)

Comment: Thank you so much haha. No idea how long I would've taken to fix this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is delete the cache files, so it is needed if you are working in production mode. In debug mode this is done automatically. For be sure, do that manually just dropping the prod folder under var if you are in 3.x, in 2.x under app.

The command to clear the cache for 2.x is:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Comment: But also check that all the namespaces are correct; you can `use`/import the class and in the Doctrine annotation specify `class=Product::class` (without quotes!). I consider this the safest, when using mapping via annotations.

Comment: Also, you can just clear the specific Doctrine cache with `php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata`