# Unknown Entity namespace alias 'Appbundle'

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I have just started my first symfony project and I'm getting the above error in a more complex situation. To narrow it down I created a new project but the error is there again :/

What I have down:

> cd /var/www
>
> sudo symfony new em
>
> cd em
>
> sudo mkdir src/AppBundle/Entity
>
> sudo touch src/AppBundle/Entity/Company.php
>
> sudo chmod -R 777 *
>
> php bin/console doctrine:database:create  // db symfony
>
> php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle
>
> sudo touch src/AppBundle/Controller/CompanyController.php
>
> sudo chmod -R 777 * // failed to write to cache

When navigating to http://em.at/app_dev.php/companies I get the error!

I already tried [Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\ORMException: "Unknown Entity namespace alias 'AppBundle'."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35417149/uncaught-php-exception-doctrine-orm-ormexception-unknown-entity-namespace-alia)

so

> php bin/console cache:clear

which resulted in

> [Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]
>     Failed to remove file    "/var/www/em/var/cache/de~/twig/2b/2bef18b12bca6cd9cb
>     d50ce5b194c23fdc85bb73d29114f27fb3793b7f085d8a.php": .

so I deleted them manually

> sudo rm -R cache/de~
>
> sudo rm -R cache/dev

but the error persists. Anyone know what's wrong?.

my files:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Company.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="company")
 */
class Company
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;

}
```

and

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/CompanyController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Company;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class CompanyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/companies", name="company_list")
     */
    public function listAction(Request $request)
    {
        $companies = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Appbundle:Company')->findAll();
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('company/list.html.twig', [
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
            'companies' => $companies
        ]);
    }

}
```

Comment: `'Appbundle:Company'` should be `'AppBundle:Company'` at `$companies = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(...`

Comment: oh man... thank you very much :) such a stupid mistake...

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the file permissions on your var folder. Form the above messages it looks like you may not have done that. Here's the reference you need:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html

Also, just in case run:

```
php bin/symfony_requirements
```

to make sure you've met all other requirements.
This will save you a lot of grief.

Comment: hey thanks for effort but @Yoshi already solved it. :) yeah that's right my  file permission sucks but i'm locale so it's fine for developing :)